# What icon should Restore (previously deleted file) button have?

Tags: icons

I have a button with a bin icon that deletes a file. What icon should the 'Restore' button have? The restore button simply undoes the file deletion.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Specific icon requests are considered off-topic for this format. Please see the help guide (https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

There is no definitive answer to this, as it needs to be compatible with the icon for deleting (as those two options are contextually connected).

However, here are some examples:

##### Material Design

[image]
[image]

##### FontAwesome

[image]
[image]

##### Adwaita

[image]